# 404 error while doing an api call to Reddit

Tags: python, reddit

According to their [documentation](http://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_hot):

This should be enough to get the hottest new reddit submissions:

```
r = client.get(r'http://www.reddit.com/api/hot/', data=user_pass_dict)
```

But it doesn't and I get a 404 error. Am I getting the url for data request wrong?

`http://www.reddit.com/api/login` works though.

Answer (score 1):

Your question specifically asks what you need to do to get the "hottest new" submissions. "Hottest new" doesn't really make sense as there is the "hot" view and a "new" view. The URLs for those two views are `http://www.reddit.com/hot` and `http://www.reddit.com/new` respectively.

To make those URLs more code-friendly, you can append `.json` to the end of the URL (any reddit URL for that matter) to get a json-representation of the data. For instance, to get the list of "hot" submissions make a GET request to `http://www.reddit.com/hot.json`.

---

For completeness, in your example, you attempt to pass in `data=user_pass_dict`. That's definitely not going to work the way you expect it to. While logging in is not necessary for what you want to do, if you happen to have need for more complicated use of reddit's API using python, I strongly suggest using [PRAW](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). With PRAW you can iterate over the "hot" submissions via:

```
import praw
r = praw.Reddit('<REPLACE WITH A UNIQUE USER AGENT>')
for submission in r.get_frontpage():
    # do something with the submission
    print(vars(submission))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, use `/hot` rather than `/api/hot`:

```
r = client.get(r'http://www.reddit.com/hot/', data=user_pass_dict)
```

Comment: That seems like a get request to reddit web than their api.

Comment: @Hick Nevertheless, it is the way specified in the documentation to retrieve the data you seek.